# SQL Server ConnectionString TCP

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp

I am currently having an issue with connecting to my SQL Server Database.

My ConnectionString is as followed:

```
connectionString = @"Data Source=tcp:192.168.1.63;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=User;Password=Password";
```

I am trying to connect to a local database with C#. Currently my Database is on the same PC as my C# code. I already tested the local connection and it works. But trying to connect it with TCP doesn't work.

I am getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I know I got the DB, ID and Password right. The IP is my IPv4 from IPConfig.

I want to test this program locally before sending it to another pc within my local network. This is why I don't use a local connection.

Does anyone know why I can't connect?

Edit:

I have already enabled the tcp/ip. (See picture)[image: SQL Configuration]

Comment: What if you use `Data Source=localhost;` instead?

Comment: Make sure to enable the TCP/IP protocol

Comment: Can look weird, but IP connections are disabled by default in SQL Server. Check them in SQL Server configuration console

Comment: @bradbury9, Thank you for your quick response. I already tried this and with no effect. (See edit)

Comment: If you changed the configuration you need to restart the SQL Server service

Comment: wow.... That did it... Thank you so much @bradbury9!

Comment: Added an anwer with the steps you followed so others can benefit from it. And yeah, I copied your screenshot ;-) If it helped you, consider marking it as useful

Comment: @bradbury9 good Idea! Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps that must be done:

1. Change the configuration and enable the TCP/IP protocol in
   the SQL Server Configuration Manager:

   [image: Sql Server Configuration Manager]
2. You need to  restart the SQL
   Server service so it reads the new settings.